# SQL2008 and SQL2008r2Express on same server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm going to add a SQL2008r2Express instance to a Win2003 server where a SQL2008 instance already exists. The new (express) instance will have another name, of course. That is to use the 10GB free database with the express edition.

Are there any issues or further readings to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be any problems.

Comment: ok, running both now.

Answer (score 0):

None but resource contention.

Regards, Danilo